# Maven + Mercurial: Error while executing command tag

Tags: mercurial, maven, maven-release-plugin

I want to release a new version of my project using the Maven-Release-Plugin.

I get the following error, though:

```
[INFO] Tagging release with the label softsmithy-lib-v0.1...                                                                                     
[INFO] EXECUTING: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/hudson/jobs/SoftSmithy-Utility-Library-Release && hg tag --message '[maven-release-plugin]  copy for tag softsmithy-lib-v0.1' softsmithy-lib-v0.1                                                                                                        
[ERROR]                                                                                                                                          
EXECUTION FAILED                                                                                                                                 
  Execution of cmd : tag failed with exit code: 255.                                                                                             
  Working directory was:                                                                                                                         
    /var/lib/hudson/jobs/SoftSmithy-Utility-Library-Release                                                                                      
  Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.                                                                                           
    Hg version: 1.7.5 (OK)                                                                                                                       


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR                                                            
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An error is occurred in the tag process: Exception while executing SCM command.

Error while executing command tag --message [maven-release-plugin]  copy for tag softsmithy-lib-v0.1 softsmithy-lib-v0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                         
[INFO] Trace                                                                                                            
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: An error is occurred in the tag process: Exception while executing SCM command.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)                         
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)                
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)                          
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)         
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)                  
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)                              
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)                                                              
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)                                                                
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)                                                                       
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)                                                     
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)                                               
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)                                       
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)                                                                            
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)                                                         
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)                                                                 
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)                                                       
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)                                                                   
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error is occurred in the tag process: Exception while executing SCM command.
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:215)                                
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:181)                                       
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)                                        
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)                            
        ... 17 more                                                                                                                       
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: An error is occurred in the tag process: Exception while executing SCM command.                                                                                                                                             
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmTagPhase.execute(ScmTagPhase.java:113)                                                       
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:203)                                         
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:140)                                         
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:103)                                         
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:211)                                       
        ... 20 more                                                                                                                              
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Exception while executing SCM command.                                                             
        at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)                                                         
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.hg.HgScmProvider.tag(HgScmProvider.java:239)                                                            
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.tag(AbstractScmProvider.java:706)                                                   
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmTagPhase.execute(ScmTagPhase.java:109)                                                       
        ... 24 more                                                                                                                              
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Error while executing command tag --message [maven-release-plugin]  copy for tag softsmithy-lib-v0.1 softsmithy-lib-v0.1                                                                                                                            
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.hg.command.tag.HgTagCommand.executeTagCommand(HgTagCommand.java:105)                                    
        at org.apache.maven.scm.command.tag.AbstractTagCommand.executeCommand(AbstractTagCommand.java:81)                                        
        at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)                                                         
        ... 27 more
```

I tried to run

```
/bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/hudson/jobs/SoftSmithy-Utility-Library-Release && hg tag --message '[maven-release-plugin]  copy for tag softsmithy-lib-v0.1' softsmithy-lib-v0.1
```

and it worked fine!

Any ideas what is going wrong?

PS: I noted that on the following site:
http://maven.apache.org/scm/matrix.html

it is mentioned that the Mercurial tag command is not supported, but it seems to execute the command (and then fails somehow). How can I use the Maven Release Plugin with Mercurial?

PPS: This only seems to happen for multi-module projects. Single POM project runs fine. I tried  -DpreparationGoals="clean install" but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

The required parent POM

```
<groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
<artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
<version>6</version>
```

uses Maven Release Plugin version 2.0

Unfortunatly, there is an issue with multi-module projects using Mercurial.
The issue goes away, when using version 2.1

Work-around: override the version in the project POM/ project parent POM.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
    <arguments>-Psonatype-oss-release</arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I filed an issue here:
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-1388

Comment: I filed another similar issue (use version 2.2.2 instead of 2.1) here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-3975

Comment: How to solve this if I'm not using maven-release-plugin to do releases. I'm using versions-maven-plugin (versions:set -DnewVersion=x.x.x) to set the version and it works fine and using maven-scm-plugin (scm:checkin and scm:tag). scm-checkin worked but scm-tag failed with similar error message: Execution of cmd : tag failed with exit code: 255.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source file for [`HgTagCommand.java`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/scm/trunk/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-hg/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/hg/command/tag/HgTagCommand.java?revision=1056959&view=markup), it includes a few places where this kind of exception is launched (i.e. "`Error while executing command`"):

The one regarding `tag [message]` is:

```
ScmResult result = HgUtils.execute( branchConsumer, getLogger(), workingDir, branchCmd );
HgScmProviderRepository repository = (HgScmProviderRepository) scmProviderRepository;

if ( !result.isSuccess() )
{
  throw new ScmException( "Error while executing command " + joinCmd( branchCmd ) );
}
```

And that don't look compatible with a multi-modules project, where you can have *multiple* Mercurial repositories.

Comment: I have only one repository for this source-base. The rest is resolved via Maven Central repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was because of `maven release` makes 3 commits (at least in mercurial):

- Prepare the release
- Make the tag of the release
- Prepare for next development iteration

And sometimes if your project or release plugin´s configuration is not right configured, the `release` get stuck in the first commit. The problem is that sometimes it already updated the release into your sonatype server, so you have to delete this fake release from the sonatype server, configurate well your parent project´s `pom.xml`, compile the project, and release again.
This is how i looked while i delete my false release `1.0.0-alpha5` in the project `bridje-parent`:

[image]

Also delete the fake `release` located in its submodules. Remember to commit changes in your `scm` server before making a `release`.
Vote if it worked for you, it happened to me very seldom.